# Run a command until return code greater than x

Tags: bash, shell, while-loop

In a bash script I need to run a command until the return is bigger than 127.

For now, i'm running the command in an subshell, with the outputs to /dev/null and printing the return code to be able to compare it with a test:

```
while [ `command >/dev/null 2>&1; echo $?` -lt 128 ]; do sleep 1; done
```

Is there an eleganter solution for it? It looks like the only use case natively supported is to test if RC == 0 or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it would be more elegant to start an infinite loop and break when the exit code is greater than 127.

```
while true; do
    command  # redirection is now optional
    [ $? -gt 127 ] && break
    sleep 1
done
```

Comment: I like the idea. Doesn't seems too hackish like mine, and there is no need to redirect to /dev/null. Thanks!